# Cordova- embed a external website into cordova app

Tags: cordova, browser, web-applications, web

I have a website. it run good in server
I'm building a cordova app to embed this website and I want to open this website into this cordova app.

I use `window.open(..., "_blank")..   window.open(..., "_selt")`
modify config.xml `<access origin....`
but when I run app in my device, website auto open in browser.

How to open website in my app?
I don't want to use iframe.

Comment: backquote your code and espcially any HTML like content otherwise it disappears as markup. Use spellchecker to get rid of spelling mistakes ("i", "wanna") and use "?" to indicate a question in English, not ";" (that is for Greek IIRC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You have already created cordova app, you need to add Inappbrowser plugin to app so you can open your website in it. [Add other necessary plugins]

To add Inappbrowser plugin use following command.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Add following line to index.js to open your website link.

```
var url = "https://www.example.com";
var ref = window.open(url, "_self");
```

ref = reference to the InAppBrowser window object, you can add Listener to object to perform additional operation. for more help related to inappbrowser plugin check this [link](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser).

Comment: Use after "deviceready" event. you should use inside "receivedEvent" block.